# Microsoft Graph schemaExtensions Authorization_RequestDenied

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph from my app via REST API `graph.microsoft.com/beta/schemaExtensions`

Here is what I did:

1. Register app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
2. Checked for all Delegated and Application authorizations
3. Got access token [without a user](http://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) based on OAuth Client Credentials Grant flow
4. Asked for Admin Consent with access token retrieved from point 3. and it was successful using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/adminconsent?client_id=xxx&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081`
5. POST to `/beta/schemaExtensions` with access token retrieved from point 3. and I have this error:

> Authorization_RequestDenied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

So here are my questions, hoping someone could help me:

1. How do I check if delegate authorization is ok after Admin Consent request?
2. Which privileges are missing to use `schemaExtensions`?

My app should work without a user, it's the preferred approach.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here.

Extensions is GA and available on the /v1.0 version.  Please use that instead of /beta.

We don't support schema extension registration using application permissions.  It requires the *Directory.AccessAsUser.All* permission today (we're also investigating if there's another less privileged permission we can use here) per the [create schema extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions) topic.

Registering a schema extension can be a separate process from your application actually using the extension to create custom data on target object instances.

As such we are making a change (should be available shortly) to allow you to register and manage schema extensions for your app using Graph Explorer. There is also a [user voice request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis?query=extension) to have a UI experience in app registration for schema registration/management.  Please vote for this if it's important to you.

I'll update this post once Graph Explorer supports registering and managing schema extensions.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll test it using user credential. One more question: reading documentation https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups (I'll try it for users instead of groups), to add custom data to an existing user, can I do it only if I am the same user or I have to be administrator? Thank you again. Silvia

Answer (score 0):

To answer the follow up question, the calling user should have read/write access to add custom data to another user. However, you can use open extensions to add custom data using /me/extensions to calling user (as long as the app has user.readwrite or higher permissions).

Comment: that's correct, but there is no way to add open extension into optionalclaims to return them back in claims in application...