# Azure Schema Extension - Error message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: groovy, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm testing Azure Schema Extensions with a simple groovy script to the Microsoft Graph API. I first query for a list of schema extensions and this seems to work (though I am not sure where the extensions in the response have been set, I assume they are there by default). I then try to POST a schema extension but this fails with this error message:

```
[error: [
   code:InternalServerError, 
   message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object., 
   innerError:[request-id:xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx, date:2018-05-14T00:46:00]]]
```

This is the code for the GET query and the response:

```
def uriTestGET = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?"
def httpTestGET = new HTTPBuilder(uriTestGET)
httpTestGET.ignoreSSLIssues()
httpTestGET.request(GET,JSON) { req ->

httpTestGET.parser.'application/json'
headers.'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + AzureToken
headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
response.failure = { resp, json ->

    println "GET Failure. GROUP: ${resp.statusLine}"
    println(json)

}
response.success = { resp, json ->

    println "GET Success. GROUP: ${resp.statusLine}"
    println(json)
}
}
```

Response

```
[   
 @odata.context:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions, 
 @odata.nextLink:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$skiptoken=XXXXXXXXXX, 
 value:[[
   id:adatumisv_exo2, 
   description:sample desccription, 
   targetTypes:[Message], 
   status:Available, 
   owner:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, 
   properties:[
     [name:p1, type:String], 
     [name:p2, type:String]]], 
   [id:circuitid_globals, 
    description:Circuit ID Graph Global Schema, 
    targetTypes:[Group, User], .. etc
```

And the following POST request:

```
def uriTestPOST = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?"
def httpTestPOST = new HTTPBuilder(uriTestPOST)
httpTestPOST.ignoreSSLIssues()
httpTestPOST.request(POST,JSON) { req ->

httpTestPOST.parser.'application/json'
headers.'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + AzureToken
headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
body = [
        "id":"TestExtension",
        "description": "Test to add user object schema extension",
        "status": "Available",
        "targetTypes": ["user"]

]

response.failure = { resp, json ->
    println "POST Failure. GROUP: ${resp.statusLine}"
    println(json)

}
response.success = { resp, json ->

    println "POST Success. GROUP: ${resp.statusLine}"
    println(json)
}
```

}

This gets the response:

```
[error:[
 code:InternalServerError, 
 message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,
 innerError:[request-id:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, date:2018-05-14T00:46:00]]]
```

---

Updated Body looks like this -

```
 body = [
        "id":"TestExtension",
        "description": "Test to add user object schema extension",
     // "status": "Available",
        "targetTypes": ["User"],
        "properties" : [["name": "ExtensionProperty", "type":"String"]]

]
```

And this is the new error message:

```
   [error:[
    code:Authorization_RequestDenied, 
    message:Insufficient privileges to complete the operation., 
    innerError:[request-id:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, date:2018-05-14T05:09:41]]]
```

---

I've decoded the token and it shows the following roles are included:

Decoding the token it states the following roles:

```
"roles":     [
   "User.ReadWrite.All",
   "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
   "User.Invite.All" ]
```

I've been adding additional permissions to get this to work, these seem to be greater privileges than is required as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi Mondo, Just for your case, I think it should be caused by missing `properties` in your request body. However, I also did a test and there are some other issues with this API, such as status value and Insufficient privileges. I will do a deep test and keep updating here.

Comment: Thanks, I've added properties, see edits above, setting the status also caused problems so I have disabled that for now. Now I get an insufficient privileges message. Do you know what privileges are required for the registered app to complete these User object extensions?

Comment: According to the documentation, it needs `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission.And this requires admin consent for it.

Comment: But in my test, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add an example of your token? That will help rule out of you're missing any scopes.

Comment: I've added the roles allowed as shown in the decoded token. (see above)

Comment: I've now trying giving the registered app every possible permission in both Microsoft Graph and Azure AD and it still fails with "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Comment: @MarcLaFleur debugging the jwt further I see that the delegated permissions are not included just the app permissions. I'm thinking that even though I added permissions that I believed override those required, the absence of the delegated Directory.AccessAsUSer.All is the issue. I suspect the answer lies in this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549105/set-the-scope-parameter-for-microsoft-graph" that you answered last year. I just need to work out how to change the initial login request to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system automatically chooses between using Application or Delegated permissions based on the OAuth Grant you've chosen:

- Client Credentials Grant = Application
- Authorization Code Grant = Delegated
- Implicit Grant = Delegated

This is because you need an actual User to authenticate if you want them to *delegate* your application to act on their behalf. Without a User authenticated there isn't anyone to delegate permissions so you need to operate under Application scopes.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The documentation for Create schemaExtension under permissions states                                                                                   
*Application  Not supported*.                                                               So when I try to test this directly via an application it will always fail with insufficient privileges. I need to create an app that authenticates a user first with the permissions ( Directory.AccessAsUser.All) to be able to create the schemaExtensions

Comment: That is correct. There are many AAD functions that do not support Application permissions. There are many reasons for this but one glaring one is that, without a user authenticated, an app would be able to simply replace user passwords without a person to attribute/blame.